# yii2 Framework get items via public variable in menu widget

Tags: yii2

i'm working with yii2 menu widget and I need get menu items via variable.Forexample:

```
Menu::widget([
'items' => $items,
'activeCssClass'=>'active',
'encodeLabels' => false,// Requested feature
'options' => [
    'class' => 'nav nav-tabs',
],
```

]);

How can call public variable suh as  `$this->params['breadcrumbs']` in breadcrumbs

```
 Breadcrumbs::widget([
'homeLink' => [
    'label' => '<i class="fa fa-home"></i> ',
    'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'encode' => false// Requested feature
],
'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
```

])

Comment: you can set them in $item .. if you have problem show a sample then i provide to answer with  a proper $item

Comment: I want to set $item where set $this->params['breadcrumbs']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have

```
<?php 

   $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Your_labe', 'url' => ['your-controller/your-action']];
   // then   
   $menuItems[] = $this->params['breadcrumbs'];

   // OR  you can set $menuItems this way 
   // $menuItems[] =  ['label' => 'Your_labe', 'url' => ['your-controller/your-action']];

    Menu::widget([
    'items' => $menuItems,
    'activeCssClass'=>'active',
    'encodeLabels' => false,// Requested feature
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'nav nav-tabs',
    ],

?>
```

If you want use the Menu widget in layout you can try thgis way

In View you assign your items this way

```
   $this->params['menu_items'][] = ['label' => 'Your_labe', 'url' => ['your-controller/your-action']];
```

In layout you can use the items this way

```
    Menu::widget([
    'items' => isset($this->params['menu_items']) ? $this->params['menu_items'] : [],
    'items' => $menuItems,
    'activeCssClass'=>'active',
    'encodeLabels' => false,// Requested feature
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'nav nav-tabs',
    ],
```

Comment: I use widget in main.php but I use $menuItems[] in views.php therefore I see  Undefined variable: menuItems error.

Comment: You want use a Menu in layout (main.php) and populate the menu with value assigne by each view ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, I fixed problem:
in main.php

```
Menu::widget([
'items' => isset($this->params['menu']) ? $this->params['menu'] : [],
'activeCssClass'=>'active',
'encodeLabels' => false,// Requested feature
'options' => [
    'class' => 'nav nav-tabs',
],
```

]);

and calling in view.php

```
$this->params['menu'] =[
['label' => '<i class="fa fa-list-ol alis"></i> List',
    'url' => ['site/index'],
],
['label' => '<i class="fa fa-plus alis"></i> Create',
    'url' => ['site/create'],
],
['label' => '<i class="fa fa-search alis"></i> View',
    'url' => ['site/view'],
],
```

];